# My Update Method don't update any data in my database in vb.net using localdb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, localdb

Sorry newbie here, I was making an inventory that could insert, delete and update. but the problem is all the data that i want to update don't really update. i always go to "Record Not Updated" then i try again to update the next problem occur is "The variable name '@date' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

`Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click`

```
    Dim iii As Integer

    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE service SET date=@date ,tech_assign=@tech_assign,err_one=@err_one,err_two= @err_two,err_tri = @err_tri,err_other = @err_other,err_other_spec = @err_other_spec,act_one = @act_one,act_two = @act_two,act_other = @act_other,act_other_spec = @act_other_spec,request = @request,op_unit = @op_unit WHERE serv_Id= @serv_Id"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech_assign", Tech_assignTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_one", Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_two", Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_tri", Err_triCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_other", Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_other_spec", Err_other_specTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_one", Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_two", Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_other", Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_other_spec", Act_other_specTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@request", RequestTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op_unit", Op_unitTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serv_Id", i)
        iii = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If iii <> 0 Then
            MsgBox("Record Updated Succesfully!", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Record Not Updated", MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If

        cn.Close()
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

@Steve Here is my whole code in the form, I use `i` from the datagridview from the other form

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form3

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\Users\Carlo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication5\WindowsApplication5\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim aa As String
Dim i As Integer

Public Sub getText(ByVal a As String)
    aa = a
End Sub

Public Sub getId(ByVal into As Integer)
    into = i
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If aa = "Save" Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button1.Visible = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button2.Visible = False

        Me.DateDateTimePicker.Text = Now
        Me.Tech_assignTextBox.Text = " "
        Me.Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Err_triCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Err_other_specTextBox.Text = " "
        Me.Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Me.Act_other_specTextBox.Text = " "
        Me.RequestTextBox.Text = " "
        Me.Op_unitTextBox.Text = " "

    ElseIf aa = "Update" Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button1.Visible = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button2.Visible = True

        Me.DateDateTimePicker.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(1, i).Value
        Me.Tech_assignTextBox.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(2, i).Value

        If Me.Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(3, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(3, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        If Me.Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(4, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(4, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        If Me.Err_triCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(5, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Err_triCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Err_triCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(5, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Err_triCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        If Me.Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(6, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(6, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        Me.Err_other_specTextBox.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(7, i).Value

        If Me.Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(8, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(8, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        If Me.Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(9, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(9, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        If Me.Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(10, i).Value = "False" Then
            Me.Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        ElseIf Me.Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(10, i).Value = "True" Then
            Me.Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        End If

        Me.Act_other_specTextBox.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(11, i).Value

        Me.RequestTextBox.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(12, i).Value
        Me.Op_unitTextBox.Text = Form2.ServiceDataGridView.Item(13, i).Value

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO service (date,tech_assign,err_one,err_two,err_tri,err_other,err_other_spec,act_one,act_two,act_other,act_other_spec,request,op_unit) VALUES(@date,@tech_assign,@err_one,@err_two,@err_tri,@err_other,@err_other_spec,@act_one,@act_two,@act_other,@act_other_spec,@request,@op_unit)", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateDateTimePicker.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tech_assign", Tech_assignTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_one", Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_two", Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_tri", Err_triCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_other", Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@err_other_spec", Err_other_specTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_one", Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_two", Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_other", Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act_other_spec", Act_other_specTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@request", RequestTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op_unit", Op_unitTextBox.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        MsgBox("New Service Has Been Save", MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        cn.Close()
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub


Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    'Dim iii As Integer
    Dim sqlText = "UPDATE service SET date=@date ,tech_assign=@tech_assign,err_one=@err_one,err_two= @err_two,err_tri = @err_tri,err_other = @err_other,err_other_spec = @err_other_spec,act_one = @act_one,act_two = @act_two,act_other = @act_other,act_other_spec = @act_other_spec,request = @request,op_unit = @op_unit WHERE serv_Id= @serv_Id"

    Try
        Using localCN = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\Users\Carlo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication5\WindowsApplication5\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
            Using localCMD = New SqlCommand(sqlText, localCN)
                localCN.Open()
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateDateTimePicker.Value
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@tech_assign", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tech_assignTextBox.Text
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@err_one", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Err_oneCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@err_two", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Err_twoCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@err_tri", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Err_triCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@err_other", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Err_otherCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@err_other_spec", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Err_other_specTextBox.Text
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@act_one", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Act_oneCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@act_two", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Act_twoCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@act_other", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Act_otherCheckBox.CheckState
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@act_other_spec", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Act_other_specTextBox.Text
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@request", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RequestTextBox.Text
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@op_unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Op_unitTextBox.Text
                localCMD.Parameters.Add("@serv_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i
                localCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                localCN.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        'If iii <> 0 Then
        'MsgBox("The Record Has Been Updated!", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        'Else
        'MsgBox("The Record Is Not Updated!", MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        'End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub form3_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        Form2.shwService()
End Sub
```

End Class

same problem occur on my first question,

Comment: The second problem happens because you use global variables, the first one (if you don't have any exceptions) probably because there is no record to update matching the integer used to find serv_Id

Comment: thanks steve. i'll try this now. i'll just tell you if any problems will occur

Comment: @Steve  the second problem is already solved but the same on the first it didn't update the data in my records in database, i edit my previous question and add my whole code. please help me. and thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use global variables unless it is really necessary. In your case there is no need to keep a global connection object and a global command object. You don't loose any performance point if you declare the variables locally. Having a global SqlCommand object means that the parameters once assigned are still there the second time you enter this block of code. Instead a local object is always recreated as new and there are no remnants of the previous call.
The SqlConnection instance instead should be disposed as soon as possible to free system resources on your local machine and on the server also.

So your second problem could be solved in this way

```
Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim iii As Integer

    Dim sqlText = "UPDATE service SET date=@date, ......"
    Try
        Using localCN = new SqlConnection (.... your connection string....)
        Using localCMD = new SqlCommand(sqlText, localCN)
             localCN.Open()
             localCMD.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  DateDateTimePicker.Date
             .....
        End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex as Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
         ' No need to add a Finally (Using statement close and dispose for you)
    End Try
```

The first problem is, with high probability, caused by the fact that there is no record with a `Serv_ID` field matching your variable `i` at the moment of the call, another possibility is that you are working with a different database than you plan to use. In particular this happens a lot when you have used the `|DataDirectory|` substitution string in your connection string

**EDIT**
Looking at your update, it seems that you have this inverted

```
Public Sub getId(ByVal into As Integer)
    ' into = i
    i = into
End Sub
```

Comment: Answer updated, check if this simple typo is the cause of your first problem